# How to asynchronously consume a WCF Data Service using paging with BeginExecute in UWP

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, uwp

I have a WCF Data Services service and its methods return  Queryable lists.

Using a Java library, I could consume it with client-side paging (using `top` and `take`).

Now I intend to consume it with an UWP application.

Unfortunately the following code does not work:

```
var result = client.CreateQuery<Information>("GetInformation")
             .AddQueryOption("id", string.Format("'{0}'", actualId))
             .Skip(index)
             .Take(amount).ToList();
```

I get this exception:

> This target framework does not enable you to directly enumerate over a
>   data service query. This is because enumeration automatically sends a
>   synchronous request to the data service. Because this framework only
>   supports asynchronous operations, you must instead call the
>   BeginExecute and EndExecute methods to obtain a query result that
>   supports enumeration.

As I had to use `BeginExecute`, I can no longer use `Skip` and `Take`.

```
var query = client.CreateQuery<Information>("GetInformation")
                  .AddQueryOption("id", string.Format("'{0}'", actualId));
query.BeginExecute((x) =>
          {
            var result= query.EndExecute(x);
            foreach (var information in result)
            {

            };                       
          }, null);
```

How should I do it with this asynchronous method?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem but with OData.
I found the solution in the next blog http://jqyblogger.blogspot.com/2013/11/linq-query-error-message-on-windows.html and basically we need to use the asyncronus tools for OData.

```
            Default.Container context = new Default.Container(new Uri("url_to_OData_Service"));
        var nquery = context.Reports
                               .Where(r => r.ReportId == 1)
                               .Select(p => p);

        DataServiceQuery<Report> query = (DataServiceQuery<Report>)nquery;

        TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Report>> taskFactory = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Report>>();
        IEnumerable<Report> result = await taskFactory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null), iar => query.EndExecute(iar));
```